# Understanding mixed strategies

Tags: game-theory, dominant-strategy

I would like help with the following:

Assume a game with two individuals. Suppose that for an individual a mixed strategy $\sigma_1$ is dominated by an strategy $\sigma_2, $ it is necessary for $\sigma_1$ to put a positive probability $p$ to a dominated pure strategy?

My guess is that it isn't necessary, since you would get a higher payoff by assigning a probability of 0 to the pure strategy that is dominated, but I can't find any way to formally argue for this or give a concise example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you would get a higher payoff by assigning a probability of 0 to the pure strategy that is dominated

This is not relevant, as no one is claiming that $\sigma_1$ is optimal in any way.

> I can't find any way to formally argue for this or give a concise example.

Study the following game with two players: 
Player 1 chooses A or B, while player 2 chooses between A, B and "pass". We are not trying to find an equilibrium, we will be focusing on player 2, laying out their payoff only. 
Should player 2 choose the same strategy (A or B) as player 1, they will get a payoff of 5. Should player 2 choose "pass" they will get a payoff of 4. In all other cases player 2 gets a payoff of 0.

Show the following:

1. Player 2 has no dominated pure strategies in this game.
2. Player 2 has a mixed strategy $\sigma_1$ (likely your first guess) in this game that is dominated by a pure strategy.